# Javascript Regex - sanitize string with whitelist

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a very basic RegEx problem.  I'm trying to sanitize an input field with a whitelist.  I'm trying to only allow numbers and a decimal into my field.  If a user types an invalid character, I want to strip it out of the input and replace the input with a clean string.

I can get it working with only numbers, but I can't get the decimal into the allowed pool of characters:

```
var sanitize = function(inputValue) {
    var clean = "",
        numbersOnly = /[^0-9]/g;  // only numbers & a decimal place
    if (inputValue) {
        if (numbersOnly.test(inputValue)) { 
            // if test passes, there are bad characters
            for (var i = 0; i < inputValue.length; i++) {
                clean += (!numbersOnly.test(inputValue.charAt(i))) ? inputValue.charAt(i) : "";
            }
            if (clean != inputValue) {
                makeInputBe(clean);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scott_in_ct/Q8es8/)

Comment: Why not just `inputValue.replace(/[^0-9.,]+)/,'');`

Comment: in ES6 I believe you can use `Number.isFloat(inputValue) || Number.isInteger(inputValue)`

Comment: I'm not. My fiddle only works with numbers, but I can't get the decimal in there.  I can't figure out the RegEx string to allow it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than looping your input character by character and validating each character you can do this for basic sanitizing operation:

```
var s = '123abc.48@#'
s = s.replace(/[^\d.]+/g, '');
//=> 123.48
```

**PS:** This will not check if there are more than 1 decimal points in the input (not sure if that is the requirement.